# Error when filtering spatial points dataframe: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘over’ for signature ‘"SpatialPointsDataFrame", "crs"’

Tags: r, polygon, point, filter, point-in-polygon

I generated two spatial datasets: a SpatialPointsDataFrame and a polygon. The polygon should filter the SpatialPointsDataFrame, based on whether the points are in the polygon or not. However when I try to filter the SpatialPointsDataFrame, the following error occurs: `Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)): error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[': unable to find an inherited method for function ‘over’ for signature ‘"SpatialPointsDataFrame", "crs"’`

The whole code:

```
#necessary libraries
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
library(tidyverse)
library(raster)

## == create points dataset == ##

#initialize coordinates
points_long <- c(11.6, 11.55, 11.7)
points_lat <- c(49.93, 49.964, 49.93)
#merge columns to one dataset
points_df <- data.frame(points_long, points_lat)

coords <- points_df[ , c("points_long", "points_lat")]   # coordinates
crs    <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") # crs

# make the SpatialPointsDataFrame object
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords      = coords,
                               data        = points_df, 
                               proj4string = crs)

## == create polygon == ##

#intialize coordinates (Bayreuth)
coor_1 = 11.5355
coor_3 = 11.6176
coor_2 = 49.9666
coor_4 = 49.9187

#define extent of polygon
x_coord = c(coor_1, coor_1, coor_3, coor_3)
y_coord = c(coor_4, coor_2, coor_2, coor_4)
xym <- cbind(x_coord, y_coord)

#transform into spatial polygon
p = Polygon(xym) #create polygon
ps = Polygons(list(p),1) #wrap into a Polygons object
poly = SpatialPolygons(list(ps)) #wrap into a SpatialPolygons object
poly_sf <- st_crs(poly, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs")) #define coor. system

#filter points based on polygon
pts_in<-spdf[!is.na(over(spdf,poly_sf)),] #this is where the error shows up
```

Alternatively, I tried to apply [these proposed solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982773/crop-for-spatialpolygonsdataframe). Applying the code
`pts_in <- raster::crop(spdf, poly_sf)` results in the error `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extent’ for signature ‘"crs"’`

and

`pts_in <- gIntersection(spdf, poly_sf, byid=TRUE)` results in the error `Error in RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :  rgeos_convert_R2geos: invalid R class crs, unable to convert`

Answer (score 1):

This line is returning the CRS of `poly`:

```
poly_sf <- st_crs(poly, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs"))
```

so when you do:

```
pts_in<-spdf[!is.na(over(spdf,poly_sf)),]
```

You are trying to overlay `spdf` with a coordinate system object, which doesn't make sense.

If you are trying to set the CRS of `poly` to a given form, use:

```
proj4string(poly) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs")
```

You can then do `over`:

```
> over(spdf, poly)
 1  2  3 
 1  1 NA
```

Note you are using exclusively `sp` class objects, so none of the functions in the `sf` package are any good to you at this point. Also, some of the packages you list aren't "necessary" - `tidyverse` especially - so you shouldn't list it since it makes it harder for people without those packages installed to run your code. Always try and remove any package requirements and make your examples *minimal*.